# Ajax call to the Application Server sitting behind firewall

Tags: reverse-proxy, firewall

We have 3 tiered architecture:

Web Server - public (web application deployed) App Server - private (webApi deployed) Db Server - private (sql server installed) And my co-worker said, we have this architecture like this, because its a standard architecture that follows everywhere.

We have been using Asp.net application, where we can make api call from Web Server to App Server without any problem.

But now we have been converting our application from Server side to Client side, i.e. we'll only have js, html & css pages in web application, but problem is, we cannot call api using ajax directly from js, because of the two reason.

our App server is on different domain. App server is behind firewall, means it can only be accessed if we are connected to VPN, or we make a proxy on Web Server, and go through that channel. i.e. js<->Web Server Proxy<->App Server<->Db Server. We want to bypass Web Server from the channel, like: js<->App Server<->Db Server without connecting to VPN, because we don't require user to connect to VPN to use our web application.

Please give your suggestions. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable CORS or cross origin resource sharing. You can research more on that but just want to give idea.